# Upper limit to number of columns I can JOIN two tables on in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join, limit, multiple-columns

Is there a limit to the number of columns I can JOIN two tables on in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the extent that there is a limit on the size of an SQL statement, then **Yes**: you cannot create an SQL statement that joins so many columns that the joining condition does not fit inside the limit on an SQL statement.

Otherwise - and in practice - **No**.  You will run out of the ability to comprehend your joins before the DBMS runs out of the capacity to handle them.